# Basic auth in Apigility when using Postman

Tags: rest, authentication, authorization, postman, laminas-api-tools

I have a very simple REST service using Apigility, exposing GET and POST methods. I test it using Postman. Everything works fine.

I then try to add an authentication layer. To do so, I create a htpasswd file, I create a Basic Auth adapter pointing to that file via Apigility interface and I select that authentication type on the settings page of my API.

I finally choose to add an Authorization request for the POST request, not the GET.

When I try to post, I'm asked for a login and a password, I type the one matching the htpasswd file content, the Authorization header is generated and the POST works great.

But when I try to make a GET request without the Authorization header, I'm still asked for a login and a password. If I cancel, I get a 401 status code (Unauthorized).

As far as I understand, if no Authorization header is set, the "guest" mode is used by Apigility, and as the GET method doesn't require authentication, I shouldn't have to enter a login and a password to access my resource.

Where did I go wrong? What didn't I understand right?

Thanks

Comment: It's not going to help much, but I just wanted to let you know that I'm having the exact same issue. Did you manage to solve this? If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I haven't managed to solve it yet, and I'm not working on it on a regular basis, so not much progress from my side. Good luck!

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157546/trying-to-use-postman-and-having-trouble-setting-basic-access-authentication-h

Answer (score 2):

You just mentioned you're doing this in Postman, and I think therein lies the issue.

The HTTP authentication has a "pre-auth" stage whereby, if no credentials are present, it includes a `WWW-Authenticate` header in the response. For machine clients (cURL, HTTPie, language-based clients, etc.), this is ignored as long as the status code is not a 401 or 403.

However, in *browser-based* clients, such as Postman, when the browser encounters such a header, they'll typically issue the authentication challenge, and send empty credentials if cancelled. This, of course, means an Authorization header is sent with invalid credentials, leading to your 401.

Try using cURL or HTTPie from the CLI; you should see very different behavior there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to update your configuration and set which methods do & don't require authentication.

Check your configuration for the following configuration:

```
[
    'zf-mvc-auth' => [
        'authorization' => [
            'Your\Controller' => [
                'collection' => array(
                    'default' => true,
                    'GET' => true,
                    'POST' => true,
                    // etc.
                ),
                'entity' => array(
                    'default' => true,
                    'GET' => true,
                    'POST' => true,
                    // etc.
                ),
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

You'll need to set the methods you want to allow without authentication to `false`.

Comment: Checked it, it's already all set. I added the default value, but still not working the way it should be.