# Access Github private repo from Postman

Tags: github

I am trying to access GitHub private repo of my organization from postman.

Here is what I am doing...

**Get EndPoint**
https://api.github.com/repos/_orgs/_repo

**Headers**
Content-Type : application/json

**Authorization**
OAUTH 2.0

I have generated personal access token from my github account and passed it as a token in OAuth.

**Response**
Status Code : 404
{
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get"
}

Any Suggestions/recommendations/thoughts would be helpful.

Thanks

**Updated**

I try the suggestion

[image]

Here password is my github token.
Make sure that you haven't passed anything along with Headers. It's worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have generated personal access token from my github account and passed it as a token in oAUTH.

It depends *how* you passed it: as illustrated [in this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11558#issuecomment-569390909), it needs to be [base64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32157792/6309) (with [`base64encode.org`](https://www.base64encode.org) for instance)

[image: postman]

The OP reports a curl works:

```
curl -i -u myusername:mypersonaltoken https://api.github.com/repos/_orgs/_privaterepo
```

From there:

> To import a cURL command into Postman.
>
> - Click on the import tab.
> - Select the Raw Text option and paste your cURL command.
> - Hit import and you will have the command in your Postman builder.

Comment: @ArslanAslam You mean you have base64 encoded your token?

Comment: @ArslanAslam Did you add in the headers the `X-OAuth-Scopes` one, as shown in https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/? And `X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes`.

Comment: I have added X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes : User in my header.

Comment: But i am not able to get success response

Comment: @ArslanAslam User? it should by user (it might be case-sensitive)

Comment: @ArslanAslam OK. Would it work with a curl, instead of postman?

Comment: I didn't try it with curl

Comment: I don't have to get worry about base64 encode as https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11558 says  " After creating the token you need to (1) base64 encode it and (2) copy-paste it in your request. In my case, I just used Postman rather than the usual cURL since the former does step 1 automatically. For Postman, simply go to the "Authorization" tab and fill-in your Username and Password (the generated token)"

Comment: @ArslanAslam OK. The idea would be to validate it first in command line (curl), then adapt it to postman.

Comment: i have tried Curl       curl -i -u username :personal_access-token  https://api.github.com/_orgs/_repo , still it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205746/discussion-between-vonc-and-arslan-aslam).