# Implementation of System.Net.NetworkCredential type in a postman request

Tags: c#, .net, postman

I have a dot net implementation of the `HttpWebRequest` to send the HTTP post request to an API.

I am sending the HTTP request as:

```
    HttpWebRequest hwr = null;

    Uri uri = new Uri(booking ? Settings.BookingUrl: Settings.AvailabilityUrl);
    hwr = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    hwr.Method = "POST";
    hwr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Username, Settings.Password);
    hwr.ContentType = "text/xml";
    hwr.KeepAlive = false;
    hwr.Timeout = 150000;
    hwr.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    hwr.Accept = "text/xml";
    hwr.PreAuthenticate = true;
    hwr.ProtocolVersion = new Version(1, 1);
    hwr.UserAgent = "";
    hwr.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

    Stream streamOut = hwr.GetRequestStream();
```

I want to replicate this exact request in a postman. But, I am stuck in sending the `NetworkCredential` in a request header. Since Credentials are an object of `System.Net.NetworkCredential` type.

[image]

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157546/trying-to-use-postman-and-having-trouble-setting-basic-access-authentication-h/32157792)

Comment: @Llama not really, the API endpoint allows the plain password and username